# Why I get this error while data insert with model?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the Model which simply inserts data into the table:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class UserHandle extends Model {
            public $timestamps=false;

                 }
```

Here is the Controller:

```
 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

 use Illuminate\Http\Request;
 use app\UserHandle;

 class UserHandleCntrl extends Controller {

  public function index(){

         $data = new UserHandle;
         $data->name='Laravel';
         $data->email='dbtcbd@gmail.com';
         $data->username='bdlaravel';
         $data->password='laravel12345';
         $data->save();
         echo 'Data Inserted';
   }
 }
```

Here is the route :

```
          Route::get('/user', 'UserHandleCntrl@index');
```

But when I am trying to insert data into the database I am getting error that model class not found. Why I am getting this and what is the solution. Please help. Bellow is the error screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a namespace issue? Use `use app\UserHandle`

Comment: Where is the PHP file defining the `UserHandle` class? What is its `namespace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep the `a` of `App` capital while you are including that model.

```
 use App\UserHandle;
```

Answer (score 1):

including model use `App` instead of `app` in your controller file.

```
use App\UserHanle;
```