# Class 'app\Models\SkillsEmployee' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

so, my model looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SkillsEmployee extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'skills_employee';

    protected $fillable = [
        'id', 'HTML', 'JavaScript','React', 'PHP', 'C#', 'C++', 'JQuery', 'Phyton', 'Symphony',
    ];


    protected $hidden = [];
}
```

and my controller is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use app\Models\SkillsEmployee;

class SkillsController extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        $Skills = SkillsEmployee::all();
        dd($Skills);

    }
}
```

Comment: Namespace is case-sensitive. Use `App\Models\SkillsEmployee`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why I get this error while data insert with model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016312/why-i-get-this-error-while-data-insert-with-model)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

even thou the folder name is app, the PHP namespace is by default App, if you use an IDE that can help you a lot in your are new in the field.

So in the Controller.

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\SkillsEmployee; // app was lower case

class SkillsController extends Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this for laravel naming conventions : https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices#follow-laravel-naming-conventions

and here you can learn php coding style https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/ with this you can lean any new php framework more easily.

**Controller : singular : ExampleController**

**Route : plural : articles/1**

**Model : singular : User**

As code mentioned by @Martin Henriksen that's how you should implement it.

Happy Coding. :)